# Error in Iot hub receiving message from device to cloud

Tags: .net, azure, azure-iot-hub

When I run the iothub demo from the Azure website (using C#), it always occurs an exception, just like that:

```
Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessagingCommunicationException was unhandled
HResult=-2146233088
IsTransient=true
Message=system detects an invalid pointer address attempts to use a pointer argument in a call
Source=Microsoft.ServiceBus

StackTrace:
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.RunSynchronously()
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Amqp.AmqpEventHubClient.GetRuntimeInformation()
at ReadFromDevice04.Program.Main(String[] args) Location： F:\XXXX\AzureCloudService1 \ReadFromDevice04\ReadFromDevice04\Program.cs:Line 22
at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

InnerException:
ErrorCode=10014
HResult=-2147467259
Message=system detects an invalid pointer address attempts to use a pointer argument in a call
NativeErrorCode=10014
Source=Microsoft.ServiceBus

StackTrace:

Server stack trace:
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.get_RemoteEndPoint()
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Amqp.Transport.TcpTransport..ctor(Socket socket, TcpTransportSettings transportSettings)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Amqp.Transport.TcpTransportInitiator.Complete(SocketAsyncEventArgs e, Boolean completeSynchronously)

Exception rethrown at [0]:
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Amqp.AmqpMessagingFactory.ConnectAsyncResult.<getasyncsteps>b__9e(ConnectAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)

Exception rethrown at [1]:
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Amqp.AmqpMessagingFactory.EndCreateConnection(IAsyncResult result)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Amqp.FaultTolerantObject`1.CreateAsyncResult.<getasyncsteps>b__4(CreateAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)

Exception rethrown at [2]:
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult`1.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Amqp.FaultTolerantObject`1.OnEndCreateInstance(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.SingletonManager`1.EndGetInstance(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Amqp.AmqpMessagingFactory.CreateManagementLinkAsyncResult.<>c__DisplayClass17a.<getasyncsteps>b__175(CreateManagementLinkAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)

Exception rethrown at [3]:
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Amqp.AmqpEventHubClient.GetRuntimeInfoAsyncResult.<getasyncsteps>b__14(GetRuntimeInfoAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)
```

This is *InnerException*:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;
using System.Threading;

namespace ReadFromDevice04
{
    class Program
    {
        static string connectionString = "xxxx";
        static string iotHubD2cEndpoint = "messages/events";
        static EventHubClient eventHubClient;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Receive messages. Ctrl-C to exit.\n");
            eventHubClient = EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, iotHubD2cEndpoint);

        var d2cPartitions = eventHubClient.GetRuntimeInformation().PartitionIds;  //////this place occured exception

        CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        System.Console.CancelKeyPress += (s, e) =>
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            cts.Cancel();
            Console.WriteLine("Exiting...");
        };

        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        foreach (string partition in d2cPartitions)
        {
            tasks.Add(ReceiveMessagesFromDeviceAsync(partition, cts.Token));
        }
        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
    }
    private static async Task ReceiveMessagesFromDeviceAsync(string partition, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        var eventHubReceiver = eventHubClient.GetDefaultConsumerGroup().CreateReceiver(partition, DateTime.UtcNow);
        while (true)
        {
            if (ct.IsCancellationRequested) break;
            EventData eventData = await eventHubReceiver.ReceiveAsync();
            if (eventData == null) continue;

            string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventData.GetBytes());
            Console.WriteLine("Message received. Partition: {0} Data: '{1}'", partition, data);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Does anybody has any idea what's wrong in my project? Thanks a lot. I was using the latest version of the `NuGet` packages, and the `Event Hub` could be created,the error just occurred when:

```
var d2cPartitions = eventHubClient.GetRuntimeInformation().PartitionIds
```

Comment: This sounds like a connection string issue from experience, you would get the same issue using the Socket class I believe. Can you confirm you are using the correct address to connect?

Comment: You might not want to share your access key

Comment: I think the connection is useful

Comment: Yes but your access key is like a password, I would seriously consider and recommend removing the access key. Event Hub connection strings start with Endpoint=sb:// do they not?

Comment: Thanks a lot.I had removed it already,so have you any other idea what the error in my project?thanks

Comment: Yes，I know that Event Hub connection strings start with Endpoint=sb://.But in the Guide (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-getstarted/).He used iot hub connection string to establish the event hub.I think it's valid too.

Comment: Any body can help me with this problem?

Comment: The error is a basic socket one, make sure everything is correct with the connection string.